# Bold axes labels (font.lab = 2) not working for sqrt-residuals-axis in diagnostics plot

Tags: r, plot

```
df <- structure(list(sales1 = c(11.3208, 12.9151, 18.8947, 14.6739, 8.6493, 9.5238, 7.6923, 0.0017, 8.0477, 6.7358, 6.1441, 21.7939, 4.2553, 0.0017, 11.0196, 6.2762, 13.2316, 5.0676, 5.6235, 14.9893 ), store = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), day = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
par(mfrow= c(2,2), mgp=c(2, .7, 0), mai=c(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1), font.lab = 2)
a1 <- aov(sales1 ~ store + day, df)
plot(a1)
```

[image: Model Diagnostics Plot]

I discovered that `font.lab = 2` works perfectly fine for all axes in the model diagnostics plot -with the exception of the y-axis on the bottom left (sqrt standardized residuals).

Is there a particular reason why this is not working and is there an easy, alternative solution to print all axes labels bold?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Sorry, that was absolutely what I intended to do but forgot to add the emmeans-package. Is the example working for you now? @Quinten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the label in the third plot is not bold is that it is created using plotmath rather than text labels (to incorporate the square root sign). This means it ignores the `font.lab` argument.

Unfortunately, this is hard-coded into `plot.lm`, which is what actually draws the plot. The only simple solution I can see for this is to create a copy of the `plot.lm` function and overwrite the appropriate line:

```r
plot.lm <- stats:::plot.lm

sub <- quote(yl <- as.expression(substitute(bold(sqrt(abs(YL))),
                                            list(YL = as.name(ylab23)))))

body(plot.lm)[[25]][[3]][[4]] <- sub
```

So now your third plot should get a bold label too:

```r
plot(a1)
```

[image]